# Unable to clone git repository in my local using Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I am trying clone a git repository from a remote server using Ansible. This is what I am trying:

```
---
# - name: '<some name>'
- hosts: localhost
  #vars: 
   # - destination: /home/atul/Workplace/test-ansible 
   # - http_port: 80
   # - max_clients: 200
- gather_facts: true
- tasks: 
    - git: 
        repo: http://<my git url>/test/test.git
        dest: /home/atul/Workplace/test-ansible
        version: master
```

I am getting this in my terminal.

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify the host or have an inventory file with the hosts in.

Try running this: `ansible-playbook <playbook>.yml -i [localhost,]`

Comment: Around 1.5 year ago that might have been a valid suggestion (though not really answering the question).

Answer (score 0):

You should define the play as a single dictionary:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks: 
    - git: 
        repo: http://<my git url>/test/test.git
        dest: /home/atul/Workplace/test-ansible
        version: master
```

In your case you have three plays with missing parameters. The first one does nothing, the second contains only `gather_facts` and that's why you get an error that the `hosts` field is missing.